# Is my question about a fake player in Minecraft not focused?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

Some days ago, I posted *[Spawn fake player with Minecraft](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70634072/10952503)*.

Such as I see a flag as "Need more focus" (and the downvote), I was really waiting for some opinion about it.

But, the [close vote review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/30770288) is invalidated (because of too many reviews I think).

So, such as I don't have any opinions, I would like to know the general one and ask here if you think my question is not focused (or maybe has another problem).

The objective of my question was simple, and with only one question: *How can I spawn a fake player in Minecraft?*

The question contains few possible ways that people can try, which are not working. And the answer propose something that is working.

Do you think my question is not focused, bad in another way, or the person who flagged was wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Your question isn't closed.

Comment: @Larnu From the sounds of it, someone flagged the question as "Needs more focus", and OP's asking whether the flag was justified.

Comment: Well, if that is the case, the fact that it got invalidated in the queue is the OP's answer, @F1Krazy , which leads us back to what is the OP actually asking. Seems like they are just looking for validation, but that could result in the meta effect and the opposite of what they want.

Comment: Unless the question is closed, the question can continue recieving answers. Why to bother a single _close vote_ ?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium because I don't want to post bad question, and because the question isn't so much viewed, so not so much people with flag privilege (and also because some of my other question get some flag/downvote, and I don't understand why too, and maybe they have the same issue as this one)

Comment: And yes, that's exactly right @F1Krazy ! Also, for the meta effect, we will see.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't worry about a single downvote/close vote. Though there is no evidence to say they are, they could have in all likelihood been the same person. As I mentioned in my prior comment, posting a question like this is more likely to cause your question to come under scrutiny and thus the meta effect. Even though your question had 1 downvote (when you asked this qusetion), your answer has 2 upvotes, so you've helped at least 2 people (or they found the answer useful) and no downvotes. If you worry about every single downvote you aren't going to have a "fun" time here.

Comment: Looks fine to me, darned good answer too. A how-to question as a how-to question should be, mostly. I need this, I tried this but that gives me an error, how to do it properly? A shame a perfectly valid question ended up in the minus, but I'm hopeful that will correct itself soon enough. For the future, post the literal error you get rather than a description of the error. Copy-paste it as it is. That might already make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for tips @Gimby ! And yes, maybe that could be better for the referencement of the question too, becuase it will contains the error that some people will get. I will include it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the review queue handled this appropriately; while one user felt that the question was overly broad, obviously other reviewers (myself included) didn't feel that way.

I don't think that this question is too broad, since it shows what you tried so far and explains exactly what went wrong.